# Passing an instance as a parameter for a foreign key reference

Tags: peewee

When I pass an instance of a model to a query for use as the fk ref, I have seen some syntax where the instance itself is suitable but in my repro it fails.

for example:

```
model_a = ModelA(name='bar')
model_a.save()
Model_b.get_or_create(name='foo', model_a_id=model_a)
# versus
Model_b.get_or_create(name='foo', model_a_id=model_a.get_id())
```

What base model feature enables the first syntax?

I am using peewee v2.7.4.

Comment: You are using a very old version of Peewee. Consider upgrading as this bug has likely been fixed.

Comment: I don't have a choice, its bundled in an constrained platform that I don't have that level of control on, otherwise that would have been my first step.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just assigning the model instance to the foreign-key name?

```
Model_b.get_or_create(name='foo', model_a=model_a)
```

If all you have is an integer ID for model_a, the above should also work.

Comment: Hi, this was what I had originally when inheriting a base model from the vendors implementation and it worked. After some issues with the vendors code, I created a very simple base model and thats when it broke. Looking through the original base model, I am baffled as to why it no longer worked and I had to manually assign the integer pk value. Thank you for help.

Comment: Ok...yeah probably a bug in the way foreign keys are inherited. I think this was fixed in a later version.